# Convert StringType Column To ArrayType In PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, pattern-matching, fpgrowth

I have a dataframe with column "EVENT_ID" whose datatype is String.
I am running FPGrowth algorithm but throws the below error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1711.fit. 
:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: 
The input column must be array, but got string.
```

The column EVENT_ID has values

```
E_34503_Probe
E_35203_In
E_31901_Cbc
```

I am using the below code to convert the string column to arraytype

```
df2 = df.withColumn("EVENT_ID", df["EVENT_ID"].cast(types.ArrayType(types.StringType())))
```

But I get the following error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1874.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`EVENT_ID`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast string to array<string>;;
```

How do I either cast this column to array type or run the FPGrowth algorithm with string type?

Comment: just use `pyspark.sql.functions.array`: for example: `df2 = df.withColumn("EVENT_ID", array(df["EVENT_ID"]))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Original answer

Try the following.

```
In  [0]: from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
         from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace, split

In  [1]: df = spark.createDataFrame(["E_34503_Probe", "E_35203_In", "E_31901_Cbc"], StringType()).toDF("EVENT_ID")
         df.show()
Out [1]: +-------------+
         |     EVENT_ID|
         +-------------+
         |E_34503_Probe|
         |   E_35203_In|
         |  E_31901_Cbc|
         +-------------+

In  [2]: df_new = df.withColumn("EVENT_ID", split(regexp_replace(col("EVENT_ID"), r"(^\[)|(\]$)|(')", ""), ", "))
         df_new.printSchema()
Out [2]: root
          |-- EVENT_ID: array (nullable = true)
          |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I hope it will be helpful.

#### Edited answer

As @pault pointed out very well in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603391/convert-stringtype-column-to-arraytype-in-pyspark#comment101678477_57608665), much easier solution is following:

```
In  [0]: from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
         from pyspark.sql.functions import array

In  [1]: df = spark.createDataFrame(["E_34503_Probe", "E_35203_In", "E_31901_Cbc"], StringType()).toDF("EVENT_ID")
         df.show()
Out [1]: +-------------+
         |     EVENT_ID|
         +-------------+
         |E_34503_Probe|
         |   E_35203_In|
         |  E_31901_Cbc|
         +-------------+

In  [2]: df_new = df.withColumn("EVENT_ID", array(df["EVENT_ID"]))
         df_new.printSchema()
Out [2]: root
           |-- EVENT_ID: array (nullable = false)
           |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: This is overkill. you can just use `pyspark.sql.functions.array`